# What is the most elegant way of doing null checks in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type, nullable

Giving an example, lets say we have a code like the one below:

```
String phone = currentCustomer.getMainAddress().getContactInformation().getLandline()
```

As we know there is no elvis operator in Java and catching NPE like this:

```
String phone = null;
try {
    phone = currentCustomer.getMainAddress().getContactInformation().getLandline()
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {}
```

Is not something anyone would advise. Using Java 8 `Optional` is one solution but the code is far from clear to read -> something along these lines:

```
String phone = Optional.ofNullable(currentCustomer).flatMap(Customer::getMainAddress)
    .flatMap(Address::getContactInformation)
    .map(ContactInfo::getLandline)
    .orElse(null);
```

So, is there any other robust solution that does not sacrifice readability?

**Edit:** There were some good ideas already below, but let's assume the model is either auto generated (not convenient to alter each time) or inside a third party jar that would need to be rebuild from source to be modified.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  Another solution would be to avoid the possibility of these things being null in the first place.

Comment: What's wrong with the try catch block you mentioned in your question?

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD Google "why using exception for control flow is bad": https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: Thank you @MalteHartwig for pointing this out to me. For some reason I always believed that try...catch blocks ought to be used everywhere, that it is a good practice and never really thought there could be a potential downside to it. This is an interesting topic, i'll look more into it..

Answer (score 5):

### The "heart" of the problem

This pattern  `currentCustomer.getMainAddress().getContactInformation().getLandline()` is called [TrainWreck](http://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck) and should be avoided. Had you done that - not only you'd have better encapsulation and less coupled code, as a "side-effect" you wouldn't have to deal with this problem you're currently facing.

### How to do it?

Simple, the class of `currentCustomer` should expose a new method: `getPhoneNumber()` this way the user can call: `currentCustomer.getPhoneNumber()` without worrying about the implementation details (which are exposed by the train-wreck).

### Does it completely solve my problem?

No. But now you can use Java 8 optional to tweak the last step. Unlike the example in the question, Optionals are used to return from a method when the returned value might be `null`, lets see how it can be implemented (inside class `Customer`):

```
Optional<String> getPhoneNumber() {
    Optional<String> phone = Optional.empty();
    try {
        phone = Optional.of(mainAddress.getContactInformation().getLandline());
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        // you might want to do something here: 
        // print to log, report error metric etc
    }
    return phone;
}
```

Per Nick's comment below, ideally, the method `getLandline()` would return an `Optional<String>`, this way we can skip the bad practice of swallowing up exceptions (and also raising them when we can avoid it), this would also make our code cleaner as well as more concise:

```
Optional<String> getPhoneNumber() {
    Optional<String> phone = mainAddress.getContactInformation().getLandline();        
    return phone;
}
```

Comment: Personally I would still advice against the try catch NPE pattern just to save (in this case) two null checks. What if `getMainAddress()` or any of the other methods do not return null, but throw an NPE? This potentially sweeps programming errors under the carpet.. but I'm fairly sure you know this too :-)

Comment: @NickL you're right: ideally `getLandline()` would return an optional which would be delegated all the way up. That would definitely improve the code! I'll adda comment to the answer.

Comment: @alfasin I like the idea of having `Optionals`, but the problem is that I usually have that problem for the model that is auto generated, from either WSDL or Swagger or present in some 3rd party library. For the former I could each time alter the code but that does not fit my definition of "elegant" ;-) . For the later example is a Prowide Software SWIFT library where you need to go deep and 80% of fields are usually null.

Comment: @domaru I'm not familiar with "Prowide Software SWIFT". When it's a 3rd party code you're using - you can implement the first approach, when you have control over *all* of the code - better use the second.

Comment: Anyway, even assuming we have full control over the code, when looking into TrainWreck anti-pattern, authors assume you want to execute method not get value. If we would like to apply the same logic in any this example we would have to write a getter named `getMainLandlineNumber()` and you could also imagine there will be a need for `getShippingLandlineNumber()`,`getMainMobileNumber()`, `getShippingMobileNumber()`, etc. That would most likely make the all classes to grow significantly. Out of the two bad ideas I would then choose going NPE way minding that "sweeping under the carpet" thing :(

Comment: @domaru I hear you, that's the tradeoff... I would probably do the same with the exception that if, for a specific field, there are many calls - I'd implement the delegation without a TrainWreck. But I would probably take your approach and not implement it to most of the fields unless needed (one such scenario is, for example, that the contract of  class `ContactInformation` changes and now I need to fix any delegation to it).

Answer (score -5):

```
String s = null;
System.out.println(s == null);
```

or

```
String s = null;
if(s == null)System.out.println("Bad Input, please try again");
```

If your question was with the object being null, you should have made that clear in your question...

```
PhoneObject po = null;
if(po==null) System.out.println("This object is null");
```

If your problem is with checking whether all the parts of the line are null, then you should have also made that clear...

```
if(phone == null) return -1;
Customer c = phone.currentCustomer();
if(c == null)return -1;
MainAddress ma = c.getMainAddress();
if(ma == null) return -1;
ContactInfo ci = ma.getContactInformation();
if(ci == null)return -1;
LandLine ll = ci.getLandline();
if(ll == null)return -1;
else return ll.toNumber()//or whatever method
```

Honestly, code that's well written shouldn't have this many opportunities to return null.

Comment: The question asker is aware that they can do this. They are asking the question to see if there is a different or better or more elegant way.

Comment: @csm_dev I have absolutely no idea what the asker is asking at this point

Comment: OP is asking how to make this chain of methods null-safe in a *more elegant way* than checking every element for `null`

Comment: Like the Elvis operator does - that operator just doesn't exist in java.